# Java switch/case going to default after case

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I'm trying to work on my homework for class, and I'm using a switch case to make a command line interface, but I'm having a problem with the part I'm using. When I execute the addCard command, it goes through fine, but then afterwards goes to the default section. When I try using any of the other sections, or use it without the try segment, it works and doesn't go to default. Any thoughts on how to repair this? Code below

```
public static void cmdLine(String Cmd) {
    switch(Cmd) {

        case "Help":
        case "?":
            System.out.println("Available Commands:\naddCard = Add a card!\ndeleteCard = Delete a Card!\nfindCard = Locate Card Number by Name!\nCard (Card Number) = Work with your card");
            break;
        case "addCard" :
            System.out.println ("Enter Account Name:");
            String cName = scan.nextLine();
            try {
                System.out.println ("Enter Account Start Balance:");
                int cBal = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println ("Enter Account Number:");
                int cNum = scan.nextInt();
                PPArray.addCard(cName, cBal,cNum);
            } catch (InputMismatchException nfe) {
                System.out.println("InputMismatchException: Please try again with only the card number. (Ex. 12345");
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "deleteCard" :
            System.out.println("here we will have a command to remove the card from the array");
            break;
        case "Card" :
            System.out.println("This will lead to a new function to operate with said card");
            break;
        case "Exit":
        case "exit":
        case "Quit":
        case "quit":
            return;
        default :
            System.out.println("Invalid Command ('?' or 'Help' for commands)");
            System.out.println(PPArray.cardArray[1].name);
    }
    cmdLine(scan.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: Can you put break points at every line in the "addCard" section and tell us at which line it jumps to default?

Comment: can you rephrase the question? there seems to be some misunderstanding when you look at those two different answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the try block in "addCard", you get input with `int cNum = scan.nextInt();`.
Then, when you call `cmdLine(scan.nextLine());` after the switch statement, it consumes the new line, which causes the default clause to be called.

You can prevent this by adding `scan.nextLine()` at the end of that try block.

```
    case "addCard" :
        System.out.println ("Enter Account Name:");
        String cName = scan.nextLine();
        try {
            System.out.println ("Enter Account Start Balance:");
            int cBal = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println ("Enter Account Number:");
            int cNum = scan.nextInt();
            PPArray.addCard(cName, cBal,cNum);
            scan.nextLine();
        } catch (InputMismatchException nfe) {
            System.out.println("InputMismatchException: Please try again with only the card number. (Ex. 12345");
            break;
        }
        break;
```

BTW, I think it is bad coding to recursively call `cmdLine(scan.nextLine());` in order to process the next input. I think a while loop would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

#### You have to actually exit the program if you want it to quit:

```
    case "Exit":
    case "exit":
    case "Quit":
    case "quit":
        return;
```

should be

```
    case "Exit":
    case "exit":
    case "Quit":
    case "quit":
        System.exit(0);
```

#### What is the next line?

```
cmdLine(scan.nextLine());
```

Is reading something that doesn't match any of the cases, your step debugger will show you where your logic error is. Step debugging is a much more valuable skill than `System.out.println()` and guessing.

Comment: this part i wanted, so that doing exit would exit out of the program itself. I'm just worried about the addCard case. it did it before i added the exit cases

Answer (score -1):

change this

```
case "Exit":
case "exit":
case "Quit":
case "quit":
     return;
```

to

```
case "Exit":
case "exit":
case "Quit":
case "quit":
      break;
```

**EDIT:**

One more little issue is `cmdLine(scan.nextLine());` taking new line each time and causing `default` to execute. Better to use `cmdLine(scan.next());` which do not accept multiple words or line.

Comment: then it will just ask for the next line and not quit, this isn't correct at all.